# How to check out with Batch , if a folder contains a .txt file and then copy the folder into an other location?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to make a script with Batch. I want from this script to check it out, If a folder contains a file, "list.txt", and if it is in the folder i want to make a copy in an other location. I wrote some lines of code but it's not working. Any ideas?

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:loop
    for /f %%i in ('dir "C:\Users\ntosis\Desktop\Draft" /ad /o:d /s /b') do ( 
    SET a=%%i
        for /R %%a %%t in (*.txt) do if "%%~nxt"=="list.txt" SET p=%%~dpnxt
        echo !p!

        IF DEFINED %p% ( robocopy C:\Users\ntosis\Desktop\Draft\%a% C:\Users\ntosis\Desktop\Copied\%a% /MOVE /E )
)

echo Folder is empty or does not exist
timeout /t 15
goto loop
```

The problem in this moment is that the second loop does  not the check right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir "C:\Users\ntosis\Desktop\Draft" /ad /o:d /s /b') do ( 
    IF EXIST "%%i\list.txt" (
        robocopy %%i C:\Users\ntosis\Desktop\Copied\ /MOVE /E
    )
)
```

Comment: this one or this one `if exist !i!\list.txt (echo ok) else (echo notok)` ?
Ok, not ok is only for test

Comment: Each folder is stored in `%%i`. You want to know if `%%i` contains `list.txt`. You can achieve this with `IF EXIST "%%i\list.txt"`. You need the quotes cuz there might be spaces in the path. So if `list.txt` is found in `%%i` `robocopy %%i C:\Users\ntosis\Desktop\Copied\ /MOVE /E` is executed.

Comment: i have a small issue, the robocopy don't make a folder in the destination folder and makes only a unsorted copy.  How can i change this line to make also a new folder ? `robocopy %%i C:\Users\ntosis\Desktop\Copied\ /MOVE /E`

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "source=C:\Users\ntosis\Desktop\Draft"
    set "target=C:\Users\ntosis\Desktop\Copied"

    for /l %%t in (0) do (

        set "found="
        for /d /r "%source%" %%a in (list.txt) do if exist "%%a" (
            for %%b in ("%%~dpa.") do (
                echo Found "%%a"
                robocopy "%%~dpa." "%target%\%%~nxb" /move /e
            )
            set "found=1"
        )

        if not defined found (
            echo folder is empty or does not exist
        )
        timeout /t 15

    )
```